# better way to synchronize Inserting with unique record number

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

i'm working on a WPF application(C#) with MVVM architecture using EntityFramework which need to insert row in the following table(Tallies) with unique "No" as custom format (yearNo-MonthNo-IssuNo):

```
ID int unique
No int e.x: 15020001
...
```

The problem is the users inserting the data synchronizlly and the No column should be unique.
the solution which i'm decided is to using a StoredProcedure but i'm looking for a better way to insert using EF and avoiding StoredProcedure's issues.
Any Idea would be appreciated.
In the other word i want to generate unique number for an insert

Comment: Why don't you use a traditional identity column ? Your RDBMS would take care of this column itself and you'll be sure to have a unique id.

Comment: Identity, or use a Guid.

Comment: What is Guid?I added identity as ID column but need to generate UNIQUE No in inserting by the described format

Answer (score 0):

2 Ways.

1) Using Identity Column: You can create Identity Column Just so your SQL will take care of the problem.

2) Using uniqueidentifier: This will create a unique id everytime so before you insert the record, generate a uniqueidentifier and save the record with the same.